# How do you change the capitalization of filenames in Git?

Tags: git, rename, case-sensitive, file-rename

I am trying to rename a file to have different capitalization from what it had before:

```
git mv src/collision/b2AABB.js src/collision/B2AABB.js
fatal: destination exists, source=src/collision/b2AABB.js, destination=src/collision/B2AABB.js
```

As you can see, Git throws a fit over this. I tried renaming using just the plain old `mv` command as well, but Git doesn't pick up the rename (as a rename *or* as a new untracked file).

How can I change a file to have a different capitalization of the same name? I am on Mac OS X v10.7.3 (Lion) with Git 1.7.9.1 using [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) (zsh) 4.3.15.

Comment: it is because the osx file system is case preserving andcase insensitive by default. You can simply proceed in two steps: `git mv myfile foo; git mv foo MyFile`

Comment: Got it working with "git mv --force myfile MyFile".

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899582/i-change-the-capitalization-of-a-directory-and-git-doesnt-seem-to-pick-up-on-it

Comment: Starting git 2.0.1 (June 2014), `git mv hello.txt Hello.txt` will work on case insensitive OS. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24979063/6309)

Comment: Linking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793735/change-case-of-a-file-on-windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I commit case-sensitive only filename changes in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683458/how-do-i-commit-case-sensitive-only-filename-changes-in-git)

Answer (score 943, accepted):

Starting Git 2.0.1 (June 25th, 2014), a **`git mv` will just work on a case-insensitive OS**.

See [commit baa37bf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/baa37bff9a845471754d3f47957d58a6ccc30058) by [David Turner (`dturner-tw`)](https://github.com/dturner-tw).

#### `mv`: allow renaming to fix case on case-insensitive filesystems

"`git mv hello.txt Hello.txt`" on a case-insensitive filesystem always triggers "`destination already exists`" error, because these two names refer to the same path from the filesystem's point of view and requires the user to give "`--force`" when correcting the case of the path recorded in the index and in the next commit.

> Detect this case and allow it without requiring "`--force`".

`git mv hello.txt Hello.txt` just works (no `--force` required anymore).

---

The other alternative is:

```
git config --global core.ignorecase false
```

And rename the file directly; git add and commit.

It does work in a CMD. It might fail in a git bash (on Windows) session (see [Louis-Caron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2881888/louis-caron)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68173364/6309))

As noted by [jaquinocode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13255028/jaquinocode) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523849/changing-capitalization-of-filenames-in-git/24979063#comment124685264_24979063), if your local repository itself has that setting:

```
git config --local core.ignorecase false
```

Comment: FWIW this regressed or never worked on Windows. Am on 2.15.1.windows.2 and still need to use --force

Comment: **Will this work for the extensions capitalization also 
For example, if have file name image.TXT and I want to rename it like image.txt**

Comment: @siluverukirankumar Yes. Did you have any issue with that usecase?

Comment: Yes, @VonC I have a use case like where I have image name extension with capital letters like **image.PNG**, but in my code I have **image.png**, I want to change to the **image.png** (assume I don't want to change in my code) when I am changing the file name in folder but it is not showing in the modified files.

Comment: @siluverukirankumar OK. Can you ask a separate question illustrating the issue, with your OS, Git and shell version?

Comment: A `git mv hello.txt Hello.txt` followed by a `git reset` would leave a `Hello.txt` in file system, not the original `hello.txt`.

Comment: how do i do this renaming from caps to lowercase for bulk of images?

Comment: @MohakLondhe Pending `--pathspec-from-file` (which is slowly added to some commands with Git 2.25, but not `git mv` yet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59505896/6309), you would need to script it, as in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15747640/6309

Comment: Got this to work on windows by running this command and `git config core.ignorecase false`

Comment: @DeepakGautam Strange. You could ask a separate question with some details illustrating your use case.

Comment: In my case, my repo's local git config had core.ignorecase set to true (I don't know why). So changing the setting to true for the global git config (by running `git config --global core.ignorecase false`) wasn't enough for me, since my repo's local setting overrode the global setting. So then I changed the local setting as well (by running `git config --local core.ignorecase false`) and that worked.

Comment: @jaquinocode Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 529):

Considering [larsks' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523849/changing-capitalization-of-filenames-in-git/10523903#10523903), you can get it working with a single command with `--force`:

```
git mv --force myfile MyFile
```

Comment: If you are on a case insensitive file system and you get a fatal error "Invalid Argument" try these steps instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011625/git-mv-and-only-change-case-of-directory

Comment: While this is the correct answer for the first step, how to you then proceed to switch to another branch under Mac OS X when the other branch has the old capitalization. I get **** error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout: ****

Comment: This failed on commit for me on Windows: `Error: Will not add file alias 'MyFile' ('myfile' already exists in index)`

Answer (score 163):

Sometimes you want to change the capitalization of a lot of file names on a case insensitive filesystem (e.g. on macOS or Windows). Doing individual `git mv` commands will tire quickly. To make things a bit easier this is what I do:

1. Move all affected files outside of the directory to, let’s say, the desktop.
2. Do a `git add . -A` to stage the removal of those files.
3. Rename all files on the desktop to the proper capitalization.
4. Move all the files back to the original directory.
5. Do a `git add .`. Git should see that the files are renamed.

Now you can make a commit saying you have changed the file name capitalization.

Comment: This comes at the expense of all history in the files you move in and out, right? I'm guessing the git mv --force doesn't have this shortcoming.

Comment: No, this would not remove all of the history. Notice that there is no commit between the two adds.

Comment: this is really what I needed. well done. it should be an answer as well. thank you!

Comment: See also @softarn's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40990382/266309), which offers a convenient one-liner to do this all at once :)

Comment: The much simpler and less hacky way to do this is `git rm -r --cached .` + `git add --all .` as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55541435/8910547) that deserves a ton more upvotes.

Answer (score 73):

File names under OS X are not case sensitive (by default). This is more of an OS problem than a Git problem. If you remove and readd the file, you should get what you want, or rename it to something else and then rename it back.

Comment: You can also `git clone` the repo on a Linux system, rename the files and commit them just for this situation (if you have a Linux system at hand).

Comment: Actually, filesystems on OS X can be case-sensitive, you can configure it on installation. [How to check if an OS X partition is case-sensitive](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/71357/122223)

Comment: ...hence the "(by default)" in the answer.

Comment: To confirm, you can use `git rm --cached fileorfolder` to remove the file or folder from git without removing the file or folder from the file system. Then you can simply add the file or folder again with `git add fileorfolder`.

Answer (score 59):

### Set `ignorecase` to `false` in git config

As the original post is about "Changing capitalization of filenames in Git":

If you are trying to change capitalisation of a filename in your project, you do not need to **force** rename it from Git. IMO, I would rather change the capitalisation from my IDE/editor and make sure that I configure Git properly to pick up the renaming.

By default, a Git template is set to ignore case (Git case insensitive). To verify you have the default template, use `--get` to retrieve the value for a specified key. Use `--local` and `--global` to indicate to Git whether to pick up a configuration key-value from your local Git repository configuration or global one. As an example, if you want to lookup your global key `core.ignorecase` (if the commands return nothing, you probably need to prefix with `sudo`):

```
git config --global --get core.ignorecase
```

If this returns `true`, make sure to set it as:

```
git config --global core.ignorecase false
```

(Make sure you have proper permissions to change global.)
And there you have it; now your Git installation would not ignore capitalisations and treat them as changes.

As a suggestion, if you are working on multi-language projects and you feel not all projects should be treated as case-sensitive by Git, just update the local `core.ignorecase` file.

Comment: And if `git config --global --get core.ignorecase` doesn't return anything. Is it `true`?? because after I set it to `false` it returns false (Windows 10)

Comment: And it seems not working as expected. I mean the desktop client see the change but after commit/sync, the filename remains unchanged online !

Comment: Worked for me (and better for multiple files than using `git mv`). I'm also assuming that by default it is considered true (i.e. it is ignoring case). Either that, or it matches the OS's policy to file name casing.

Comment: THAT is THE answer. Just used it.

Comment: This should be the selected answer

Comment: Changing the global setting may not work because the local setting is overriding it.  If it is not working for you check both.

Answer (score 12):

You can open the ".git" directory and then edit the "config" file. Under "[core]" set, set "ignorecase = true" and you are done ;)

Comment: seems that it should be changed to false such that git would be case-sensitive?

Comment: Yep, exactly. I personally have when git invokes a `smart` behavior and attempt to convert line endings of my files. A shitty `smart` feature that I currently detest very much, as I mainly code under Windows for Linux machines so I say `checkout as is, commit as is`.

Answer (score 9):

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24979063/2881888) by [Vonc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) is totally correct, but there is still a potential situation where your rename action would not work with git for windows:

Let's say you want to rename dir/mypath to dir/myPath:

```
git mv dir/mypath dir/myPath
```

but it fails reporting:

```
Rename from 'dir/mypath' to 'dir/mypath' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)
```

The problem is that the bash has silently replaced your command line `dir/myPath` with `dir/mypath` because it has detected that such a path exists with a different capitalization.

The solution is to use an intermediate move operation:

```
git mv dir/mypath dir/mypath_temp
git mv dir/mypath_temp dir/myPath
```

Answer (score 7):

To bulk `git mv` files to lowercase on macOS and git bash on Windows:

```
for f in *; do git mv "$f" "`echo $f | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"`"; done
```

It will lowercase all files in a folder.

Comment: it also works on windows in git bash. thanks for saving me a lot of time! :)

Comment: @VincentGagnon glad to hear! Updated the answer with that info.

Answer (score 2):

Working example:

```
git mv ./src/images/poster_video.PNG ./src/images/poster_video.png
```

Comment: Your answer does not solve the original question. You are lowcasing the extension

Comment: I am looking exactly this, but for 500 images. i want to rename ./src/images/TESTIMAGE.png to ./src/images/testimage.png on git

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the file name to uppercase , you can simply go to github repo & press .   i.e dot =>this will open up the online editor. Make your changes & commit your changes there only using source control icon on the left.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This Python snippet will `git mv --force` all files in a directory to be lowercase. For example, foo/Bar.js will become foo/bar.js via `git mv foo/Bar.js foo/bar.js --force`.

Modify it to your liking. I just figured I'd share :)

```
import os
import re

searchDir = 'c:/someRepo'
exclude = ['.git', 'node_modules','bin']
os.chdir(searchDir)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(searchDir):
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in exclude]
    for f in files:
        if re.match(r'[A-Z]', f):
            fullPath = os.path.join(root, f)
            fullPathLower = os.path.join(root, f[0].lower() + f[1:])
            command = 'git mv --force ' + fullPath + ' ' + fullPathLower
            print(command)
            os.system(command)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the following changes on Windows in Sourcetree:

[image]

I solved it by removing the file from the file system:

[image]

Then simply discard the file I want to keep and commit:

[image]

Now everything worked as expected.

[image]

Based on this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66121726/3850405