# How to commit only the file names listed in an external file

Tags: git, version-control

I have a source tree with a bunch of modifications. I selected a big list of files and put then into a file. Is there a way to commit only these ones?

I want something like:

```
git commit --files "/tmp/files-to-commit.txt" -m "Fixed bug"
```

Comment: In the txt you have the file with their completed path rooted in the project root?

Comment: @WilliamSeitiMizuta yes, each line.

Comment: With Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), that --files option of yours would be `git commit --pathspec-from-file`. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59347972/6309).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files was stagged already, therefore I did not need to add them using **git add**. Besides, I didn't want to remove other files stagged together, I just wanted to commit a specific set of files.

I got it by this way:

```
git commit <first-file-of-list> -m "Fixed bug"
```

Then, removed the *first-file-of-list* from file list and commit the others using:

```
cat /tmp/files-to-commit.txt|while read file; do
    git commit $file --amend --m "Fixed bug"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
git add `cat /tmp/files-to-commit.txt`
git commit -m "Fixed bug"
```

The `` do shell expansion. So if you have the names of files in a file, cat'ing them out will list them as args.

Comment: This doesn't work. I get errors like "error: pathspec '<filename>' did not match any file(s) known to git."

Comment: @carlo Try doing a `git add \`cat files-to-commit.txt\``, then a `git commit -m "message"`

Comment: I have a lot of other files stagged, that is why I'm trying to avoid to go this way.

Comment: @CarloPires the solution suggested in this answer works for me. Did you noticed that the before `cat` there is a back quote ( ` ), not an apostrophe ( ' )?

Comment: @niculare I think it's because I have 351 file names (one per line) and the shell expansion limits isn't enough.

Comment: @CarloPires then try to split this into multiple files.

Comment: @CarloPires You could do a bash for loop. `for f in \`cat file.txt\`; do echo adding $f; git add $f; done`

Comment: `xargs -d\\n git add <filelist.txt` -- the `-d\\n` part just allows whitespace in filenames if you happen to have that

Answer (score 0):

With Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), 6 years later, a few commands (`git add`, `git-commit`, `git reset`) learned to **take the pathspec from the standard input or a named file**, instead of taking it as the command line arguments.

See [commit e440fc5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e440fc5888bd5faf1775fc61621caa3c5fab96b6), [commit 66a25a7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/66a25a7242e4e16480eab89da6557f90a2924c12), [commit 64bac8d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/64bac8df972782b3b3dd2841699f076c7573c1db), [commit d137b50](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d137b5075660d633ef93342974350f1d0657a54c), [commit 24e4750](https://github.com/git/git/commit/24e4750c969b844536af1d286e7d977c74c078a2) (19 Nov 2019), and [commit add9770](https://github.com/git/git/commit/add97702ed7cc3aa57b15c50b72606eb2f2f8cf5) (06 Nov 2019) by [Alexandr Miloslavskiy (`SyntevoAlex`)](https://github.com/SyntevoAlex).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c58ae96](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c58ae96fc4bb11916b62a96940bb70bb85ea5992), 10 Dec 2019)</sup>

Example:

> ### [`commit`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e440fc5888bd5faf1775fc61621caa3c5fab96b6): support the `--pathspec-from-file` option
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Alexandr Miloslavskiy</sup>
>
> Decisions taken for simplicity:
>
> 1. For now, `--pathspec-from-file` is declared incompatible with `--interactive/--patch`, even when `<file>` is not `stdin`.
>      Such use case it not really expected.
>      Also, it would require changes to `interactive_add()`.
> 2. It is not allowed to pass pathspec in both args and file

The [`git commit` man page](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c58ae96fc4bb11916b62a96940bb70bb85ea5992#diff-48bff4ea1f433db2bf841a615e395d74R281-R294) now includes:

> ```
> --pathspec-from-file=<file>:
> ```
>
> Pathspec is passed in `<file>` instead of commandline args.
>   If `<file>` is exactly `-` then standard input is used.
>   Pathspec elements are separated by LF or CR/LF.
>   Pathspec elements can be quoted as explained for the configuration variable `core.quotePath`
>
> ```
> --pathspec-file-nul:
> ```
>
> Only meaningful with `--pathspec-from-file`.
>   Pathspec elements are separated with `NUL` character and all other characters are taken literally (including newlines and quotes).

---

Still with Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), the above series (teaching "`--pathspec-from-file`" to "`git commit`") forgot to make the option incompatible with "`--all`", which has been corrected.

See [commit 509efef](https://github.com/git/git/commit/509efef789de51f5d68e5c9799918f9a5ea09670) (16 Dec 2019) by [Alexandr Miloslavskiy (`SyntevoAlex`)](https://github.com/SyntevoAlex).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ff0cb70](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ff0cb70d456f586c94f15daa67d2ff1bb8e75fb6), 25 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`commit`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/509efef789de51f5d68e5c9799918f9a5ea09670): forbid --pathspec-from-file --all
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Phillip Wood</sup>
>   <sup>Signed-off-by: Alexandr Miloslavskiy</sup>
>
> I forgot this in my previous patch `--pathspec-from-file` for `git commit` (Commit [e440fc58](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e440fc5888bd5faf1775fc61621caa3c5fab96b6)).
>   When both `--pathspec-from-file` and `--all` were specified, `--all` took precedence and `--pathspec-from-file` was ignored.
>   Before `--pathspec-from-file` was implemented, this case was prevented by this check in `parse_and_validate_options()` :
>
> ```
> die(_("paths '%s ...' with -a does not make sense"), argv[0]);
> ```
>
> It is unfortunate that these two cases are disconnected.
>   This came as result of how the code was laid out before my patches, where `pathspec` is parsed outside of `parse_and_validate_options()`. This branch is already full of refactoring patches and I did not dare to go for another one.
>
> Fix by mirroring `die()` for `--pathspec-from-file` as well.