# Can I use "git checkout --" on two files?

Tags: git, git-checkout

Is it possible to use git checkout -- on multiple files in order to discard the changes?

If so how would I specify multiple files?

Comment: git checkout -- .

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Run the command multiple times

```
git checkout -- path/to/file/one
git checkout -- path/to/file/two
```

Or specify the multiple files in the same line:

```
git checkout -- path/to/file/one path/to/file/two
```

You can also specify entire folders which will recurse to all files below them.

```
git checkout -- path/to/folder
git checkout -- . # for the current path
```

Answer (score 9):

I accidentally modified all files in a directory by running find in my user's git repo directory.

```
me@server:/home/me/gitrepo# git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   .bashrc
    modified:   dir/ec2-user.pem
    modified:   dir/readme.txt
    modified:   dir/root.pem
    modified:   dir/ec2-user.pem
    modified:   dir/readme.txt
    modified:   dir/root.pem
    modified:   dir/ec2-user.pem
    modified:   dir/ec2-user.pem.pub
    modified:   dir/readme.txt
    modified:   dir/root.pem
```

To correct my mistake I ran something like this command to find all modified files and checkout the files from master.

**`git status | grep modified | sed 's/^.*modified:   //' | xargs git checkout`**

Answer (score 4):

Possible option could be:

```
git status --porcelain | cut -c4- | xargs git checkout
```

Comment: How do I filter this command to ignore certain extension files ?

Comment: You can try to add one more pipe statement with list of files for exclude (-f key for grep to exclude list of files) or provide specific file name directly.

Single file:
git status --porcelain | grep -vF sing-file-name-to-exclude.extention | cut -c4- | xargs git checkout. Or multiple files:
git status --porcelain | grep -vFf list-of-excludes.txt |cut -c4- | xargs git checkout

Answer (score 3):

Use the following command

```
   git checkout path/to/fileName path/to/fileName2 path/to/fileName3
```

This will allow you to revert or discard your changes to the files fileName, fileName2 and fileName3

**Note**: that spaces in the path name will cause an issue with git. Use single quotes '' to encase the path name in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

List the two (or more) files in a file.

With Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), a few more commands learned the "`--pathspec-from-file`" command line option, [which I previously mentioned for `git commit`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59347972/6309).

That means you can use the [old confusing `git checkout` command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24384951/6309), or the [new command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309) (Git 2.23+) [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) with a *list of files* (to checkout/restore), instead of reaptinng multiple time the same command on different files.

See [commit a9aecc7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a9aecc7abb52c4dcd616ee8f43ce5741a15e14a6), [commit cfd9376](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cfd9376c1dbe32a42bc877524940cceebd898106), [commit 8ea1189](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8ea1189eacab039fec58b0616bc814d5c03301f8), [commit 6fdc9ad](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6fdc9ad2596cb28cd882eecf4183168d44c4cbb8), [commit 1d022bb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1d022bb43fee1671c9dd69a35ffb36e73e157520), [commit bebb5d6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bebb5d6d6bf64d5b5f175af81db1e0e2fa1c5ccb), [commit 21bb308](https://github.com/git/git/commit/21bb3083c3859b4d1d222e9f883ecad42f2e886c) (03 Dec 2019) by [Alexandr Miloslavskiy (`SyntevoAlex`)](https://github.com/SyntevoAlex).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 135365d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/135365dd991f9520406012e30ab27a8d22951df8), 25 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`checkout, restore`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a9aecc7abb52c4dcd616ee8f43ce5741a15e14a6): support the `--pathspec-from-file` option
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Alexandr Miloslavskiy</sup>
>
> Decisions taken for simplicity:
>
> 1. For now, `--pathspec-from-file` is declared incompatible with `--patch`, even when `<file>` is not `stdin`. Such use case it not really expected.
> 2. It is not allowed to pass pathspec in both args and file.
>
> `you must specify path(s) to restore` block was moved down to be able to test for `pathspec.nr` instead, because testing for `argc` is no longer correct.
>
> [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) does not support the new options because it doesn't expect `<pathspec>` arguments.

---

With Git 2.26 (Q1 2020) adds more tests.

See [commit f94f7bd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f94f7bd00d06c6b651a0e7afcc90ac86cc5f391b) (30 Dec 2019) by [Alexandr Miloslavskiy (`SyntevoAlex`)](https://github.com/SyntevoAlex).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 96aef8f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/96aef8f68404964c48d0d85ce04f6b2d84097246), 30 Jan 2020)</sup>

> ### [`t`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f94f7bd00d06c6b651a0e7afcc90ac86cc5f391b): add tests for error conditions with --pathspec-from-file
>
> Suggested-By: Phillip Wood  Signed-off-by: Alexandr Miloslavskiy  Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to what already has been answered I would do something like this for the current path:

```
git checkout ./*
```