# Checking out specific file from git repository

Tags: git, clone, git-pull, git-clone, git-checkout

I have a git repository named demo.In that git i have a file named details.This details file contains some filenames listed in it.My requirement is that when i checkout the repository, I want only the files whose names are in details file to be pulled and other files shouldn't be checked out.I have tried sparse  checkout , but sparse checkout helps to pull files of a sub directory in a repository while my need is that the files which are listed in details file alone should be checked out.Could you suggest me ways to do it?

Comment: Seems like you're trying to reinvent `.gitignore`, which exists for this kind of things but works the opposite way : listed files are (as in the name) ignored from git track kist. Could it achieve what you want ? (might depend on your directory structure)

Comment: @RomainVALERI .gitignore performs the option while check in rite that is during push ,i want the same operation during checkout from repo.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a [`git clone -n`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt--n) to avoid *any* checkout.

Then you would checkout only the "details" file.

Finally, [with Git 2.25 (Q1 2020)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59505896/6309), you actually can use that file to checkout only the paths specified in it.

See [`git checkout --pathspec-from-file=<file>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt---pathspec-from-fileltfilegt): it will read the content of the file and check out only said content.