# How to merge a branch from another repo and exclude some files?

Tags: git, github, git-merge

Suppose I have a branch from another repo (`yyy`), which I want to merge into the current one (`xxx`).

But I want to exclude some files, like `config.js`, `options.js` and `views/home.ejs`, so that they stay as they were in my current repo `xxx` even if they have been changed in `yyy`.

How do I do that?

I figured out how I could merge the branch from another repo (below), but what should I add to keep these 3 files intact?

```
git remote add yyy git@github.com:yyy/yyy
git remote update
git checkout -b newbranch
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories yyy/master
```

Answer (score 1):

The advice in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68459372/341994) may  work, but I would advise that you don't do it. These instructions will arguably create an "evil merge". This makes the true history impossible to trace. Never introduce external alterations into a merge commit. The merge commit should consist entirely of *the results of the merge*. (That could involve resolving a merge conflict, but then you must be even more careful to do nothing other than resolve the conflict.)

Instead, merge, then restore the overwritten individual files and make a *new* commit, to make explicitly clear what happened. (And use `git restore`, not `git checkout`.)

Comment: If you ever want to push your changes back, I would suggest you don't get yourself in the situation to start with and don't add changes to your own repo that you would not want to push back. I know that is easier said than done sometimes, but it is worth considering if you should be saving such changes.

Comment: @matt could you please explain how I can do that sequence of steps: merge, restore, and make a new commit? I'm not so proficient in Git, so would be great to better understand what I need to do to avoid any errors. Thanks!

Comment: Also, is this maybe just better to consider one repo as an original another one as a fork? In that case, does the procedure change?

Answer (score 0):

You can merge and then restore the files from the previous commit (from your `xxx` repo), and commit again with the `--amend` option (edit the previous commit, which should be the merge).

```
#all stuff before
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories yyy/master
#solve all conflicts and be sure the merge is successful (appears in the log)
git log #find the commit hash before the merge, where your files where as you want
#if you cannot find it, try xxx/master, it should be the last upstream
git checkout <that hash> -- yourfile1 yourfile2 yourfile3
git commit --amend
```

Beware of spaces in the filenames, in case your files have spaces in their names, either quote them or escape them with a \ (if you use tab completion, this should happen automatically)

Comment: Thanks! How do I list several files? With a comma?

Comment: Just list all of them separated by a space. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28555062/can-i-use-git-checkout-on-two-files