# How do I change case of the names of multiple files, already committed?

Tags: git, macos, filenames

I want to rename all 500 images which I had uploaded on Git to lowercase.

Git ignores the casing if I push the code with lowercase images.
Is there any specific command to fix it?

OS: MAC

Comment: Git shouldn't ignore the casing unless you use case-insensitive file system. What OS do you use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change case of a file on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793735/change-case-of-a-file-on-windows)

Comment: macOS.
I also want to delete the existing images with capital letters.

Comment: Using git 2.38.1 (2022) I was able to fix casing problems with a simple `git mv`, like `git mv -v Side{b,B}ar.js`. The file has to be already in the repo or at least staged.

Answer (score 3):

> Git ignores the casing if I push the code with lowercase images ...

This is not actually true.

To understand the problem properly, you need to know the following things:

- Git doesn't store *files*, but rather *commits*.
- Commits *do* store files, but *not* in the same way your computer does normally.  The files stored inside commits have case-sensitive names, always.
- `git push` sends *commits*.

In this sense, Git is perfectly capable of replacing all the uppercase-only names in commit *X* with new lowercase-only names in new commit *Y*, while keeping all the content of each file the same.  That is, in commit *X*, you would find file `X:PATH/TO/FOO.JPG`, and in commit *Y*, file `Y:path/to/foo.jpg` would be "the same file" as the earlier one, except for the fact that its name is now in all lowercase instead of all uppercase.

Note that files inside commits have long paths that appear to have folder names in them.  As far as Git is concerned, they're still just files with these long paths.  The fact that your *computer* requires that something first create a *folder* named `path`, then another one in `path` named `to`, so that it can have a file in there named `foo.jpg` that you'll access as `path/to/foo.jpg` ... well, that's your *computer's* problem; Git will do its best to adapt to it.

This is where the name-casing issue comes in as well.  Your *computer* insists that the folder named `PATH` and the folder named `path` are *the same* folder.  It won't make both!  If you try to create a new folder named `to` in the folder named `path`, and the folder named `PATH` exists, your *computer* insists on putting the folder named `to` into the folder named `PATH`.  Worse, if the folder named `TO` exists in the folder named `PATH`, your *computer* insists on using that, instead of creating a new one.

If neither of these are already in the way, your computer will go ahead and create `path`, and then `path/to`.  So one option you have<sup>1</sup> is to *remove* everything in `PATH/TO`, remove the folder `TO` entirely, and then remove everything in `PATH` and remove the folder `PATH` entirely.  Now Git can create `path` and `path/to`.

Whatever may be going on with `path/to` or `PATH/to` or `path/TO` or `pAtH/tO` or whatever, now suppose that Git wants to create or modify the file named `foo.jpg` within this folder.  If there is no file with that name, your computer is happy to create a new one and preserve the all-lowercase name, so that you wind up with `foo.jpg` in there.  But if there is already a file named `FOO.JPG`, any attempt to create a new `foo.jpg` and write to it just writes to the existing `FOO.JPG`, which retains its shouty uppercase name.

In other words, this is not *Git's* problem.  This is *your computer's problem*.  Of course, Git is running on your computer, which makes it your—and Git's—problem to deal with.  But it's important to understand what precisely is at fault here: it's your computer, not Git, doing this to you.  If we make your Mac stop doing this to you, the problems vanish: file name case suddenly *matters*, the way Git thinks things should be, and everything else just works.

---

<sup>1</sup>Obviously, you have other options as well: you could just rename `PATH` to `I_LIKE_YELLING_PATH`, for instance, which retains all your existing files.  Eventually you can rename it back, or move files out of it, or whatever.

---

#### The easiest way to fix it is to use a file system that does not fold case

On a Mac, you could spin up a VM running Linux (see, e.g., https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/264527/linux-vm-installation-on-macbook-pro-with-macos-sierra-10-12, which is old but probably still works; I have a Linux VM with VirtualBox that I use for all kinds of things on this particular laptop).  The default Linux file systems don't think that `README` is the same file as `ReadMe`, and will let you put *both* files into the file system.  Git works really well here, which is probably not surprising.

(As I understand it, VMs work well on Windows too, and are probably the easiest way to go there.  I don't "do" Windows, though.)

You can also make a non-case-folding file system.  I do not recommend reformatting your main file system as case sensitive (see https://superuser.com/questions/203896/case-sensitive-folder-names-in-os-x), but you can make a mountable image, or use a USB stick.  For instance, using the Disk Utility, create a new blank image.  Name it something like `case-sensitive`—this will be the name for the `.dmg` file—and place it somewhere you can reach easily, e.g., `Desktop` or `Downloads`.  Make it big enough, e.g., 1 GB should be plenty.  For the `Format`, select a *case sensitive* file system such as `Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled)`:

[image: making case sensitive journaled fs]

Change the `Name` field too, just above the `Size` (I had forgotten to do this at the point I made the screenshot).  That is, the `Save As` should be a memorable name for the `.dmg` file, and `Name` should be where you want the disk to show up in `/Volumes` whenever you mount it.  Click `Save` and once it's done, click the `Done` button to dismiss the popup.

You can now mount this file system any time (Disk Utility has already done it for right now; later, just double click the `.dmg` file) and use `cd /Volumes/case-sensitive` in a Terminal window or tab.  Here you can clone and work with case-sensitive repositories, and not have to worry about case.

#### Now that you have a case-sensitive local file system, clone your repository and rename your files

```
cd /Volumes/case-sensitive
git clone <url>
cd <clone>/<path>
```

You're now ready for renaming.  There are lots of ways to do this.  See [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59515095/1256452) for a sample bash script.  Here is a `/bin/sh` shell fragment that works on MacOS:

```
for name in *.JPG; do
    lc=$(echo $name | sed 'y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/')
    echo git mv $name $lc
done
```

Run this once to make sure you like the product, then again with the `echo` removed so that it actually issues `git mv` commands.

My own preferred method is to dump the file names into a `/tmp` file:

```
ls *.JPG > /tmp/x      # note: ls, not echo, to get one per line
```

then to edit the `/tmp` file in place into the right series of commands, in `vim`:

```
vim /tmp/x
:%s/.*/git mv & \L&/
```

Once the result looks right, I write out the temp file and exit (`ZZ` or `:x`) and then execute it.  Remove it when done:

```
sh /tmp/x
rm /tmp/x
```

You are now ready to make any other changes needed, `git commit`, and `git push` from this case-sensitive directory within this case-sensitive file system in `/Volumes/case-sensitive`.

(Once you're done with the case-sensitive-file-system `.dmg` file, you can eject and delete it, as you would with any `.dmg` file.  You can also keep it as long as you like, if it's not using up too much space.)

Answer (score 0):

Pending `--pathspec-from-file` (which is slowly [added to some commands with Git 2.25, but not `git mv` yet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59505896/6309)), you would need to script it

See for instance "[How to commit only the file names listed in an external file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15747640/6309)"

The idea is to list your images in a file, then apply the new name (as in "[How to convert a string from uppercase to lowercase in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11392248/6309)").

> I also want to delete the existing images with capital letters.

And use "[bash script: check if a variable is in `[A-Z]`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/299528/7490)" to detect all uppercase names.

```
cat /tmp/images_to_rename.txt|while read image; do
    if grep -q "[A-Z]+" <<< ${image}; then
      git rm ${image}
    else
      newName=${image,,}
      git mv ${image} ${newName}
    fi
done
```