# Git - case sensitivity issue

Tags: git, github

I have a repository that is a fork. At some point i needed to merge changes from upstream and I did so. There were some conflicts and I fixed them. I don't remember well but I think I unstage some of the files during fixing conflicts. After everything is done I start to face something strange and i can't fix it.

The problem is there are six files always there as modified no matter what I do(`checkout` doesn't affect them). I thought it may fix so I removed my fork and reforked but when I clone and change branch from master to the branch I was creating pull requests I had the same issue again.

- I can't checkout files
- I can't checkout another branch
- Stashing doesn't work fork them (the files are there as modified)

*I can provide more details if needed*

Comment: Is your OS Windows ? If you run `git show HEAD:path/to/dir`, where `dir` is the directory that contains one of the faulty files, do you see two names for that file, with different uppercase/lowercase characters ?

Comment: It's macOS, yes I can see two files one with lowercase one with uppercase

Comment: @LeGEC do you know what is the solution? I really need it.

Comment: Note that on MacOS, you can make a case-sensitive file system volume and mount it, and simply work in the case-sensitive volume, to deal with this.  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59516454/1256452) to a related question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a case sensitivity issue : when git tries to checkout both files `foo` and `Foo` on disk, since your filesystem is case insensitive, one of the files "wins" and overwrites the content of the other.

Often : one of the filenames is "wrong" and you can get rid of it.

If this is your case : just run

```
git rm --cached Foo  # the variant with the incorrect casing
```

and check that the file on disk is named with the correct variant of the name.

You also want to get the correct content for your files : you can see what was stored for `foo` and `Foo` in the `HEAD` commit using `git show` :

```
git show HEAD:foo
git show HEAD:Foo

# overriding the content of 'foo' with 'HEAD:Foo' :
git show HEAD:Foo > foo

# dumping into two temp files for comparison and cmd+C/cmd+V :
git show HEAD:foo > foo.tmp.lo
git show HEAD:Foo > Foo.tmp.up
```

Once you have sorted out how files should be named in git and what there correct content is, you can `commit` or `commit --amend`.