# How to resolve a case issue in Git branch name?

Tags: git, github

I have a branch in a Github repo with a name like this: `feature/X/mybranch`. A colleague has made changes to my branch, but committed them to `feature/x/mybranch`. Github, being seemingly case-sensitive, made a separate branch with his commit.

The issue now is that my Git client only sees one branch (I am on macOS), the original one with upper case. This gives all sorts of issues. Initially, I couldn't even see his commit, and without knowing what the real issue was, I tried different things and I was finally able to get his changes after a `git reset --hard`. However some side effects are still present. For instance, my client keeps telling me I have commits that haven't been pushed, even though I can see them in Github.

Ideally I just want to merge his branch into my and delete it (or even just delete since I am pretty sure I have all his changes), but I have no idea how to do that. As mentioned, my client (tried both in terminal and Sourcetree) only sees one branch, and I don't really know what would happen if I delete that.

Comment: I would make sure, that everything is on remote repo. Then delete one of branches (and your colleague should do too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several interlocking problems, all of which stem from a single issue: macOS *file systems* default to case-folding, so that a file named `README` can be opened using the name `readme`, and vice versa.

Git sometimes stores branch name-and-value sets in a single file (`.git/packed-refs`), and when it does so, the names are case-sensitive, so that `feature/X/mybranch` and `feature/x/mybranch` are unrelated branch names.  But Git *sometimes* stores the name *as a file name* (in/for which the slashes become folder name delimiters), with the hash ID contained in that file, and here, any attempt to use `feature/X` as if it were separate from `feature/x` fails, so that you end up with just one file named `mybranch` in a folder whose name is either `x` or `X`.

The easiest way to fix it, by far, is to work within Git on a case-sensitive file system.  For instance, if you have a Linux machine—or virtual machine—you spin up that Linux system, clone the GitHub repository, and now everything Just Works and you have the two different branch names and can fix everything easily, update GitHub, delete the undesired name, and so on.  This also covers all the file-name-within-a-commit issues since you can now have two different files whose names are `README` and `readme`.

You don't *need* to use a separate VM, though, because macOS allows you to create a case-sensitive disk image and mount it.  You can then do your work in this mounted volume.  This solves most of the problems; the remaining ones are decomposed vs composed Unicode (two different ways to name a file `agréable` for instance), which Linux allows but macOS still forbids.

To create a case-sensitive disk image, see [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59516454/1256452) to [a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59511102/1256452).  This covers many more situations than your immediate one.

---

Given your immediate situation, though, there's a simple and direct way to do this *without* fussing with a Linux VM or case-sensitive file system, by doing most of the work *on GitHub itself*.  It's a little bit tricky as you need to make sure you have the right commits available locally, but a `git fetch origin` gets them.  You then need to use the `FETCH_HEAD` file that `git fetch` writes—in `.git/FETCH_HEAD`—to extract particular hash IDs.

The contents of `.git/FETCH_HEAD` are mostly self-explanatory.  It contains the branch name as seen on the other Git, and the hash ID (plus some other stuff): one entry per line, on multiple lines, corresponding to the branch names in that other Git.

From your own Git, you can then:

```
git push origin <hash-id>:<good-name>
git push --delete origin <bad-name>
```

to the Git at GitHub.  The first command—which may require `--force` in some cases (if it does, be careful here, and consider using `--force-with-lease=refname:hash:`)—will create or update the *desired* branch name with the desired casing, using the fact that GitHub itself has case-sensitivity.  So you now have the "right" branch name available there, set to the right hash ID.  The second command will *delete* the name with the undesired casing.

You may also want to use `git branch -r -d` to delete the remote-tracking name, if it has the wrong case:

```
git branch -r -d <bad-name>
```

Your own Git can now deal with the Git repository over on GitHub because it has only the good name to deal with, so now:

```
git fetch origin
```

behaves well, and does what you need.

(None of the above is tested; there could be typos.)

Answer (score 2):

Create a temporary branch on top of your current branch and switch to it

```
git switch tmp
```

From there, you can safely delete your local branches

```
git branch -d feature/x/mybranch
git branch -d feature/X/mybranch
```

(you might have to use `-D` if git protests the branch is not fully merged to its upstream branch)

Finally, recreate your branch with the right case:

```
git switch feature/X/mybranch
```

Comment: Perhaps it wasn't clear in my question, but I only have one branch locally, i.e. `feature/X/mybranch`. I cannot even see the `feature/x/mybranch` other than in Github.

Comment: @pajevic Perfect. Delete it, recreate it with the right case, and you are good to go.