# Removed dev Pkg before free (1.6 and 1.7)

Tags: git, julia

Crosspost [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/removed-dev-pkg-before-free-1-6-and-1-7/72428).

I `add`ed a package and then `dev`ed it and then removed it before `free`ing it. Now I am getting an error that I can’t fix. I removed the registries directory and also downloaded julia 1.7 and started fresh (for new `Manifest` and `Project` files), but I get the following error:

```
(@v1.7) pkg> add https://github.com/jacob-roth/PowerDynamics.jl.git
     Cloning git-repo `https://github.com/jacob-roth/PowerDynamics.jl.git`
ERROR: failed to clone from https://github.com/jacob-roth/PowerDynamics.jl.git, error: GitError(Code:ERROR, Class:OS, could not remove directory /Users/myuser/.julia/clones/231828409692979274/refs/remotes/origin/compathelper/new_version/2020-08-01-00-06-19-852-2271493462': parent is not directory: Not a directory)
```

The clone `/Users/myuser/.julia/clones/231828409692979274/` does not exist. What can I do? I've tried `rm`ing the package `PowerDynamics`, downloading a fresh version of julia and retrying, and also deleting the whole `.julia/` directory, but i still get the same error.

Answer (score 5):

The repository at https://github.com/jacob-roth/PowerDynamics.jl.git is (whether accidentally or deliberately) unfriendly to macOS and Windows users: there is one branch there named `CompatHelper`, and then a series of three branches named `compathelper/new_version/date`.  You can see these in the GitHub view by going to [this URL](https://github.com/jacob-roth/PowerDynamics.jl/branches/all).

On a Linux or Unix box, `CompatHelper` is a completely different file-or-directory name from `compathelper`.  So it's possible to create both a *file* named `CompatHelper`, and a *directory* named `compathelper`, in the same location in the file system.  But on the default setup on your macOS system, it is *not* possible to do this.  Git thinks it *should* just happen automatically, and hence just work, but it doesn't, and this is causing your `git clone` to fail.

This particular Git bug will probably eventually be fixed, but for now, clone the repository into a case-sensitive file system.  You can create one easily on your macOS system; see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59516454/1256452).  This will sidestep most other problems, although macOS still can't create certain names that Linux can.

Answer (score 3):

Can't reproduce but maybe

```
>rm PowerDynamics
```

would help. Also, you can delete `PowerDynamics` from Manifest.toml and Project.toml manually if it's stuck.