# Duplicated file with different case in git origin (bitbucket)

Tags: git

I am trying to rename files from foobar.php to FooBar.php which is quite a challenge in Git. So far I have found out that I had to set up the git config value of `ignorecase` to `false` (why it was set to true on Mac OS X, anyway?). I have managed to rename those files successfully in my local repository, but after I pushed it to BitBucket I've got `FooBar.php` as well as `foobar.php` there. How do I get rid of these duplicates? Thanks.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

### Case-insensitive, case-preserving

The problem you likely have is that the default file system on a mac is case-insensitive but case preserving; it is not possible in that circumstance for `file.php` and `File.php` to exist at the same time - they are considered the same file.

This is easy to demonstrate:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ mkdir example
$ cd example/
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /private/tmp/so/.git/ 
$ touch readme
$ git add readme 
$ git commit -m "adding readme"
[master (root-commit) 05fdf7d] adding readme
 0 files changed
 create mode 100644 readme
$ mv readme x
$ git status 
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#  deleted:    readme
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       x
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
$ mv x README
$ git status 
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 andy  wheel  0 Aug  1 19:38 README
```

In the above the file is now named `README` yet according to git the file `readme` exists and is unmodified.

### Use two commits

So instead of renaming the file (which on a case-insensitive system is problematic) do it as two steps:

```
$ mv file.php /tmp
$ git rm file.php
$ git commit -m "deleting file"
$ git push
```

**Make sure that the undesired file is gone** from the repository. Then, move the file back to the right location and add it.

```
$ mv /tmp/file.php File.php
$ git add File.php
$ git commit -m "adding File"
$ git push
```

Comment: Thanks! I have done that in one step, like

`git mv foobar.php foobar.php.bak`
`git mv foobar.php.bak FooBar.php`
`git commit -m "Renaming files."`

It looks like it should work.

Comment: It's strange. It did work on files in one directory (I have got the correct case and duplicates on BitBucket are gone). However, it did not work on files in another directory (I have got deleted files in git status, I committed them and pushed to origin, but there are still those duplicates on BitBucket). I'll try your way now.

Comment: Ok, I have done exactly your way and I still have those duplicates on BitBucket (both FooBar.php and foobar.php with the same commit message "Adding file."). Any other idea how to manage to do such a complex and complicated process as the file renaming apparently is?

Comment: What you mean by "what repo"? It's my private repo. Now I decided to remove whole directory. I removed in (moved to /tmp), commited, pushed and the directory is still on the BitBucket. Every file has "..." next to the name and size.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what that means (I'm not sure what you're doing and don't know what you mean with `Every file has "..." next to the name and size`) I recommend you get some interactive help such as [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) or #git on freenode irc. OR check out your repository (repo) on any server you have access to and correct the case problem there, commit and push.

Comment: Huge thanks for this! This has been driving me nuts for a long time, and only worked itself out over time. Now I know what to do next time.

Comment: This helped a lot. But I did it a bit simpler and it worked perfectly: `Move to subfolder`, `git add .`, `git commit -m "..."`, `git push`, `Move back from subfolder`, `git add .`, `git commit -m "..."`, `git push`

Answer (score 26):

## Applied to Directories

As I was struggling with this issue on a directory level (rather than on a file level), here is the recipe applied to a folder (this was on Windows, git v2.9.2).

- **Bitbucket** would be showing two subfolders, say *Foobar* and *FooBar*, with different files/folders beneath them.
- On the **client** *core.ignorecase* was set to *true* and both file trees where merged into one under a common root, say *Foobar*.

  - Don't set *core.ignorecase* to *false* just yet, as it will leave you suddenly with "untracked" files from the other path!
- `git mv Foobar Foobar.tmp` - You will get a set of renamed files, but also a set of deleted files and their corresponding untracked ones from the other path.
- `git add .` - Stage all the deleted/untracked files.

  - That worked ok for me. Although these appear as deletes/additions, the history of those files is not lost (magically).
- `git commit -m"syncing Foo[Bb]ar into temp. folder"` - Commit the temp. folder.
- `git mv Foobar.tmp FooBar` - Now rename from temp. to the desired name.
- `git commit -m"moving FooBar into place"` - Commit the target name.
- `git push` - Now Bitbucket should show a single subdirectory *FooBar*.
- `git config [--global] core.ignorecase false` - Never stumble into that problem again.

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what i needed, and for the record. Git is some kind of voodoo magic. Amazing :D

Comment: I thought I was losing my mind until I found your solution. Thanks!

Comment: This was a life-saver. I'm curious why a second `git add` isn't needed.

Comment: @McGuireV10 Some Git commands like ‘rm’ or ‘mv’ immediately stage their effects.

Comment: @ThomasH thanks -- is the first `git add` just a precaution, then (staging anything that might be hanging around from previous work, I assume)?

Comment: @McGuireV10 It is not to do with unrelated activities. The first `mv` command will usually result in some files from the second directory that your local Git considers "untracked", and untracked files need to be added explicitly, in order to be included in the following commit.

Comment: @ThomasH ah of course, makes perfect sense. Thanks again.

Comment: You are my hero :D

Answer (score 6):

Clone/checkout into a case-sensitive file system (on Mac OS X you can just make a case-sensitive disk image to do so), and then `git rm` the file with the capitalization you don't want.

As to why `ignorecase` was set to true, the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) says:

> **`core.ignorecase`**
>              The default is false, except `git-clone(1)` or `git-init(1)` will probe and set
>              `core.ignorecase` true if appropriate when the repository is created.

Since your Mac probably has a case-insensitive filesystem (it's the default), `git` will have noticed that and set the flag appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My Mac OS X is case sensitive, but when I pull the origin/master to my local master branch, I only see files with correct capitalization, there are no duplicates. There are, however, on BitBucket. Or did you mean something else? I am sorry, I am new to git.

Comment: Are you sure you have a case-sensitive filesystem?  That would be a bit strange.

Comment: I am sorry, I was under impression (all these years...) that as the Mac OS X is supposed to be *nix-like system, it is case-sensitive. Apparently, it is not, which is bit of shock for me, to be perfectly honest. Thanks for all responses, I will try to deal with this new situation so nobody on 1 Infinite Loop would get hurt.

Comment: HFS+ is by default case-preserving but case-insensitive.

Comment: Yep, now I do realise that it is the matter of the filesystem, not the operating system. Makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

A easy & quick fix would be to rename the affecting root folder back and forth:

Example:

```
mv src src-tmp
git add .
git commit 'step 1'
git push origin your-branch
mv src-tmp src
git add .
git commit 'step 2'
git push origin your-branch
```

This should take care of all file case issues (if fixed in your local copy)

Answer (score 2):

I got the following changes on Windows in Sourcetree:

[image]

I solved it by setting my desired case, in this case `constants.ts`.

Moved the file so git removed the file with wrong case and then commit.

[image]

Then simply move the file back:

[image]

Now everything worked as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable case-sensitivity in git

   git config core.ignorecase true
2. Git remove the file ( Git will now say foobar.php is missing and FooBar.php is deleted )

   git rm FooBar.php
3. Git commit the file "FooBar.php" (  Please make sure commit only the file you dont need- here I am removing the caps filename file )
4. Push the changes and revert the missing file.
5. revert to case-insensitive

   git config core.ignorecase false