# pushed using ignoreCase option, now 2 files exist in my repo, how to delete?

Tags: github, bitbucket

I wanted to rename my file Fugazi_SJC.yaml to FUGAZI_SJC.yaml. Used the option of "git config core.ignorecase false" but instead of renaming, it added a new file as shown below:

[image]

Now how to delete the lower case file?

Comment: Have you tried git rm Fugazi_SJC.yaml? If you do that and then git status, does it show you the lowercase file deleted?

Comment: if I do this, it shows "deleted:    FUGAZI_SJC.yaml"

Comment: You could download that file, remove it from git and recommit it - that’s one option. Here’s a similar question that could also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000138/duplicated-file-with-different-case-in-git-origin-bitbucket

Comment: `core.ignorecase` is set by Git to help remind itself what the case for the current file system is.  You're not supposed to set it yourself, and doing so can break things, as you've seen.