# Travis-CI cannot find relative module require

Tags: node.js, travis-ci, commonjs

I have a Travis build job that is running mocha tests, however the build is failing with the error:

`Error: Cannot find module './sources/reddit'`

My file tree is the following

```
feeds/ 
     sources/ 
          Reddit.js
     Feeds.js
app.js
```

Within Feeds.js I am doing

```
var https   = require('https'),
    q       = require('q'),
    Reddit  = require('./sources/reddit');
```

However it seems to be flagging up an error loading it up.

Answer (score 11):

This error is because I was referencing `./sources/reddit` with `reddit` as lowercase, on the filesystem the file is `Reddit` with an uppercase `R`.

Mac OSX deals with case sensitivity well, Linux does not.

Comment: I would say the opposite : Linux deals with case sensitivity well, Mac OSX does not...

Answer (score 4):

I also just ran into this issue, but the capitalization issue was harder to detect.

When I first checked the file into `git`, it was named `container.js` (lower-case "c"). I subsequently changed it to `Container.js`, so it reflected the upper-case name on my file-system.

Git, however, doesn't detect the case change on case-insensitive OSs so every time travis-ci runs, it ran against the lower-case name and so failed the build. (See [Changing capitalization of filenames in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523849/changing-capitalization-of-filenames-in-git) for details on how to do this properly)

I solved this by simply renaming the file and changing all references so that git picked up the new name.

Answer (score 2):

To complete others's responses, another situation where you can run into a similar issue on CI, is simply that your required files are **ignored from Git**. So locally, there are tthere, but not when Travis builds.

So make sure there is no rule in your `.gitignore` that prevents those files to be checked in.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this insane case mismatch on MacOS:

- Locally dir name is in lower case: `landing` (checked with Finder, terminal and VS Code)
- On GitHub the first letter is in upper case: `Landing`

Of course, no CI can handle that: both Travis and CircleCI failed to build.

**A solution for GitHub case mismatch:**

- rename your file/dir to something else like `file1` and commit changes
- rename it back and commit changes