# Travis CI: Cannot find module 'immutable'

Tags: travis-ci, gulp-karma

[Here's the build with the error](https://travis-ci.org/davidleston/timer/builds/53504589). I've tried [changing the Travis CI configuration](https://github.com/davidleston/timer/commit/e161a4f1b5b6e09e177e8587d9742713eede522f). I have found [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431595/travis-ci-cannot-find-relative-module-require) that ended up being [case sensitivity](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1112). In these questions, the direct dependency couldn't be found. I am not directly depending on 'immutable'. There's only one indirect dependency through [browser-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-sync).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a transient error with Travis CI - it's working now.