# Unable to rename a file in Git

Tags: git

I want to rename `SystemDBContext.cs` to `SystemDbContext.cs` and when I try renaming the file like this:

```
git mv SystemDBContext.cs SystemDbContext.cs
```

I get the following error:

```
fatal: destination exists, source=BabyChangeFinder/DataAccess/SystemDBContext.cs, destination=BabyChangeFinder/DataAccess/SystemDbContext.cs
```

I checked the directory; the destination definitely doesn't exist:

```
$ ls
SystemDBContext.cs
```

Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: use `mv SystemDBContext.cs System.DbContext.cs` without using `git`

Comment: I want the rename tracked in git

Comment: What Git version are you using? This should work with Git 2.0.1+ (http://stackoverflow.com/a/24979063/6309)

Comment: Looks like I'm using `git version 1.9.5.msysgit.0` FYI I'm using windows and have been able to rename a file before?

Comment: `git mv --force` is no longer needed with git for Windows 2.3.5 (https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)

Comment: @NRKirby just fyi, git does not track renaming files _explicitly_. `git mv` is only for  convenience; see [here](https://git-scm.herokuapp.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository#Moving-Files);

Comment: @NRKirby you're running Windows, which is case-insensitive. When git goes to move the file to the new name, Windows tells it that there's already a file with that name, because the old name and the new name are the same as far as Windows can tell.

Comment: @NRKirby: Thanks for editing the answer to match the corrected filenames.  FYI, you don't need to call out yours edits with 'Edit by OP'.  Just put the changes in.  People who want to can look at the edit history and see who did what.  Cheers! =)

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler: It wouldn't let me save the change I wanted as I was editing less than the minimum required character count, that's why I added the msg I did..

Comment: @NRKirby: OIC.  No worries, then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

`git mv --force SystemDBContext.cs SystemDbContext.cs`

or

`git mv -f SystemDBContext.cs SystemDbContext.cs`

Comment: Awesome!!, I think it can be done also in this way "mv -f filename.cs newfilename.cs "

Comment: I'm in year 2023, and using git `git version 2.40.0.windows.1`, and I have already run the command `git config --local core.ignorecase false`, but I still need the `--force` option. If not, I got the same issue as OP.