# Capitalization of filenames storing Python classes

Tags: python, pep

**C++**

I use a rigorous rule of capitalizing class names.

Over many years I tried to use the somewhat inconsistent rule of using lowercase names for the files—when writing in C++.

For example, `class Stopwatch` would be in the files `stopwatch.hpp` and `stopwatch.cpp`.

I am not sure at this point how or why I found that this is awkward, but I'm reasonably sure that it turned out to be. I use exactly the same case for the files. One benefit is that it helps avoid [annoying issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38309106/704972) in version control on OS X.

**Python**

[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends lowercase names for modules and packages. It makes no recommendations regarding filenames holding classes.

Is there such a recommendation or some best practices?

Comment: See this [similar question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/308972/python-file-naming-convention) on Programmers.

Comment: "Best Practices" really relate to technical methods that have some objective evidence supporting their benefits. Naming conventions are rather arbitrary.

Comment: It's best practice to group multiple classes in one module, so the module is normally not named after one class.

Comment: Why are you applying a Python style guide to C++?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I wasn't. I inserted headings to make it clear.

Comment: @Daniel Ah! So that's the catch. I was also moving a rigorous rule I apply in C++ to Python: Never put two classes in the same file.

Comment: Figured as much. I have removed the C++ tag since it doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In python each file is a module so to follow PEP8 your code should be as follows

```
from stopwatch import Stopwatch
```

Therefore the file should be stopwatch.py