# Git keep creating wrong files

Tags: git

Each time someone pushed to develop, Git is creating the wrong path with small letter like `/work/someDirectory/me.php` instead of `/work/SomeDirectory/me.php`

That give us untracked files as `/work/SomeDirectory/me.php` and `/work/someDirectory/me.php` with the small letter cannot be found even it gives it is created

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: is the someone using a mac?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I commit case-sensitive only filename changes in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683458/how-do-i-commit-case-sensitive-only-filename-changes-in-git)

Answer (score 1):

Check if your [Mac filesystem is case sensitive or not](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71357/how-to-check-if-my-hd-is-case-sensitive-or-not).
And [set `core.ignorecase` to false](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33732203/6309).

Then, [with Git 2.0+, record the right case with a `git mv`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24979063/6309).
Try and push that commit, and see if a new `git clone` still exhibit the case change.