# How to remove files which differ in capitalization in a Git repository?

Tags: git, macos

In my repository, there are some files that has same name, only difference is the first letter is capital or not, like `products.sql` and `Products.sql`.

I made a file with small letter when I created, but later I renamed it to first character capital. I didn't remove it from my local computer, just renamed it and committed to Git. But when I checked the repository, there are two of all, capitalized and not!

I want to remove `products.sql`, not `Products.sql` only (of course, they are in same path). I tried this:

```
git rm products.sql
```

but it removes both `Products.sql` and `products.sql`! I don't know why is it happening. As I know, by default, Git is case-insensitive, so before I renamed the files, I was changed the git config to case sensitive to prevent those kind of happening, but looks like I totally failed.

Is there a way to remove those unnecessary files safely? I'm using Bitbucket so I can remove from web, but hey, there are plenty of them, and I want to remove them entirely at once.

Comment: executing git on Windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing capitalization of filenames in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523849/changing-capitalization-of-filenames-in-git)

Comment: @phts Nope, I'm using MacOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git config --global core.ignorecase false
```

should fix it.

EDIT:
This is odd, especially since you're not on windows. A solution would be to copy Products.sql to some other folder (not git controlled), then `git rm`, then copy back the file then commit.

Comment: I already did it before renamed the file to capitalize first letter. Type **git config --list** shows **core.ignorecase=false**.

Comment: Try manually retrieving the file after rm - updated my answer.