# Unable to Resolve Module in React Native App

Tags: react-native

I'm getting an error in React Native saying it can't resolve a module. It's saying a certain folder doesn't exist but the path isn't accurate. It is telling me that `Directory /Users/user/Desktop/RNApp/app/app/containers` doesn't exists. I have no idea where that second app is coming from in the path though. My directory looks like this

[image]

This is how I am exporting my container components in `app/containers/index.js`

```
export RNAppNavigator from './Navigator/RNAppNavigator'
export SplashContainer from './Splash/SplashContainer'
export AppContainer from './App/AppContainer'
```

So I should be able to import them like `import {AppContainer} from '~/containers` correct? I don't get an issue with any other components. Just the `AppContainer`.

Thanks!

Comment: Once I made a file called `Index.js` but imported `index.js`. Hello Case-sensitive-imports, my old friend.

Comment: Hi , this was 2016 but i have same error, if you know answer pls help.

Comment: Hi, this is 2023 and I have same error, is there anyway to fix this WITHOUT restarting the Metro? When I restart Metro everything is fine, but this take too much time, everytime I create new screen I have to restart it.

Answer (score 197):

`react-native start --reset-cache` solved the issue. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1924

Comment: This throws -  ERROR  Metro Bundler can't listen on port 8081

Comment: perhaps you kept your emulator open

Comment: @sandeeptalabathula that issue is due to metro running in some terminal, close it and it will work.

Comment: Hi, this is 2023 and I have same error, is there anyway to fix this WITHOUT restarting the Metro? When I restart Metro everything is fine, but this take too much time, everytime I create new screen I have to restart it.

Answer (score 24):

If you are having similar issues with pure components or classes, ensure you are using `.js` extension instead of `.jsx`.

Comment: I wouldn't even use my components because I was using `.jsx`, does that mean React Native does not support jsx files?

Comment: Yes, I believe React native doesn't have support to JSX files.

Comment: Just to clarify, I am using Expo, I think it's Expo that does not support `.jsx` files, I wouldn't know with the pure native approach though.

Comment: @GilbertR., I built an app with pure React Native, and it doesn't support `.jsx` files too. You can check it [here](https://github.com/darde/react-native-sidemenu)

Comment: i had TSX and jsx in expo , later I ejected , every thing worked with jsx and tsx extension apart from one custom import that was in jsx (was working in expo), stopped working in bare flow, thanks to your answer, I renamed the file and worked like a charm

Comment: I can't understand why `.jsx` won't be valid file extension for a react-native filename.

Answer (score 16):

I was losing the will to live over this error, RN telling me that an imported file `./Foo` did not exist when it was right there!

The actual underlying error was **not a typo** but actually in **another file** that `./Foo` imported.

Be careful. If you are writing `JSX` anywhere (eg. in `./Bar`):

`<Bar>...</Bar>`

then you must have:

`import * as React from 'react'` (or similar)

present in that file (`./Bar`).

When the syntactic sugar (angled brackets) is transpiled it naively spits out something like:

`React.createComponent(...)`

And if `React` has not **explicitly** been imported this reference will be invalid, so the evaluation of this dependent file subsequently fails.

Unfortunately the result is that consequently `./Foo` (as well as `./Bar`) will be unavailable in your app, and thus RN says unhelpful things like `module not found` and `Indeed, none of these files exist`.

Hope that helps.

ps. you can also experience similar misery if you have circular dependencies between files! Such fun!

Answer (score 6):

For me, using **expo**, I just had to restart expo. `ctrl + c` and `yarn start` or `expo start` and the run on ios simulator or your device, whichever you're testing with.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, I fixed that by below steps:

1-> delete node_modules by:
rm -rf node_modules

2-> delte Pods folder inside ios folder:
cd ios
rm -rf Pods

3-> clear metro bunder:
rm -rf ${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/metro-*

4-> reset cache
npx react-native start --reset-cache

Now install node_modules and pods by below commands

1-> npm install

2-> cd ios

3-> pod install

4-> npx react-native run-ios

This work for me, Thanks

Comment: It works for me like a charm. In the above steps, I think rm -rf ${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/metro-*  command removes the metro cache and it solves the issue. +1

Comment: this is the only one that worked for me. I only needed rm -rf ${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/metro-*

Answer (score 4):

Based on your folder structure, try import like this in index.js:

```
import { AppContainer } from './App/AppContainer';
```

If you are using a named export, that is if you are doing:

```
export class AppContainer [...]
```

If you are using a default export, such as:

```
export default class AppContainer [...]
```

The object destructuring will fail. You have to do instead:

```
import AppContainer from './App/AppContainer';
```

Comment: Ok. I'll give it a try when I get home. i vaguely remember running into something like that a while back. I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. It just gives me another error. This time though it is saying a directory that actually exists doesn't exist lol. It is saying `Directory /Users/user/Desktop/RNApp/app/App/AppContainer doesn't exist` when it clearly does. I'm absolutely stumped.

Comment: @staxwell In which file you are actually importing the AppContainer? Since you are saying export is done in app/containers/index.js.

Comment: exporting is done in `app/containers/index.js` importing is done in `app/index.js`

Comment: @staxwell Oh, can you try this: `import { AppContainer } from './containers/index';`

Comment: Didn't work :( I'm betting there is a typo somewhere but I've been over it about a hundred times and haven't spotted anything.

Comment: @staxwell Hmm, would you mind post the source for AppContainer.js?

Comment: The code is up here :) https://github.com/MaxwellGover/react-native-pomodoro/tree/master/app/containers/App

Comment: @staxwell Thanks. Can you change how you export the AppContainer to `export { default as AppContainer } from './App/AppContainer';` in `app/containers/index.js`. Then, import it using `import { AppContainer } from './containers/index';` in `app/index.js`.

Answer (score 2):

Hardware -> Erase all content and settings
did the job for me (other things didn't).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the module is defined in the package.json use `npm install` and then try `react-native link`

Comment: React-native does automatic linking from 0.60 version onwards.

Answer (score 2):

If your file path is correct then check any one file contains

```
import React from './node_modules/react';
```

replace it with

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same issue, now it is resolved. If you are facing issues with pure components or classes, make sure that you are using .js extension instead of .jsx.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue by adding a file extension '.js'. I was using Intellij and created a js file, but it did not have the file extension. When I did a refractor rename and changed my component from 'List' to 'List.js' react native then knew how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using react-native CLI and I just restart rn-cli, `ctrl+c` to stop the process then `npx react-native start`

Answer (score 1):

1. `Reset Metro Bundler cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*`
2. `react-native start --reset-cache`

Comment: Hi! Try to add some more explaination to your solution

Comment: I get `zsh: no matches found: /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` did it change?

Comment: Metro Bundler cache can now be found here: `rm -rf ${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/metro-*`.  Source: https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/troubleshooting/

Answer (score 1):

using this worked for me `npm cache add <package name><@version>`.

Example:

```
npm cache add react-native-paper@0.1.9
```

Answer (score 1):

If none of these worked for you try deleting your ‘node_modules’ folder, then run:

```
npm install
```

Hopefully this fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Unable to solve module 'module-name' is realated to the node modules packages and sometime you would need to clean the node_modules folder and reset the application.
For beginners this would do the trick.

```
npm install
```

or

```
yarn install
```

Delete your node modules and reinstall if shows further errors.

> Remember yarn and npm although its basically the same, they have yarn.lock and package-json.lock files, So also depends on the project.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your error is coming from the outer index.js file, not this one. Are you importing this one as `'./app/containers'`? because it should just be `'./containers'`.

Comment: In my /app/index.js file I `import {AppContainer} from '~/containers`. When I try `./containers` I get another error saying another directory doesn't exist somewhere else.

Comment: It says it can't resolve module `./containers` when I try that.

Comment: Not sure then, in AppContainer you're doing export default and not just export right? Other than that, try to rebuild your app on xcode and see if the errors go away.

Comment: Yeah and I've already tried rebuilding. Hm. I'll figure it out and I'll let you know what I find out. Thanks again!!

Comment: np, can you post a ss of your app/index.js?

Comment: I've updated the question with app/index.js screen shot.

Comment: it sets the root as app? because I remember seeing an error that it's looking for app/app/containers

Comment: `~/containers` would tells `babel-root-import` to start at the `/app` folder and then look in containers folder. The `rootPathSuffix` in `.babelrc` specifies which folder is the root.

Comment: and if you use ./containers, what error did it give?

Comment: It says it's unable to resolve module ./containers from Navigator/RNAppNavigator.js Directory /Users/User/Desktop/RNApp/app/containers/Navigator/containers doesn't exist. I'm just getting all these weird paths.

Comment: yea...no clue why it's going into Navigator folder to look for containers.

Comment: when you run your package manager try 'react-native start --root'

Comment: Ok I'll give it a shot in a few hours. Will this command launch the simulator as well? I know that `react-native run-ios` does. I feel like I have run the start command before but it didn't launch the simulator.

Comment: No, but it will start up the packager for you. I think there's an issue with using RN and that library you're using for filepaths.

Comment: OK. I might just go back to the default way of importing. Not worth the headache.

Answer (score 0):

This is my project directory structure

[image]

And i use the import like this

[image]

And it is working do not forget to add dot before slash
for example './src/container/home/profile/index'

Answer (score 0):

reload the app and the cause of this error is the changes of files location made in react-native dependency which other libraries like native-base point to.

To solve it you need to view the mentioned file and change the file location to the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the node folder and restarting  works for me(run npm install after restarting)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to import using an extended file path

i.e:

WRONG: `import MyComponent from "componentFolder/myComponent";`

RIGHT: `import MyComponent from "../myAppFolder/componentFolder/myComponent";`

Both of these showed no Typescript errors, but only the bottom one worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you recently had a name change in git that only includes changing the case of file. MacOS will ignore the change. So, you will have to go to the file in console and change the name. for example if name change is `menu.js` -> `Menu.js` use terminal to do a manual rename after the pull.

`mv menu.js Menu.js`

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and then I realized that my package.json file was mostly empty. Make sure you have all the dependencies you have first.

use `yarn add DEPENDENCY_NAME` to add dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

In react native `.jsx` is different file than `.js`. That's why I was getting this error. I was trying to import `Comp.jsx` when I needed to name the file `Comp.js`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got error like below,

```
App.js (0:1)
Unable to resolve module 'module://../components/Card.js'
(Device)
  Evaluating module://../components/Card.js
  Evaluating module://App.js.js
  Loading module://App.js
```

I cleared the above error,

1. by checking the app.js import lines. File location was wrong. I made error in below line,

   import Card from "../components/Card";
2. Also i didn't write `export default app;` this line.

Comment: @Tuzi Check whether my answer helps

Answer (score 0):

I had the error and in my case i simply installed the module at the wrong location (i wasn't using the Terminal at the root of my project).

Check your package.json, if you don't see the name of the referenced module in the list, that's probably your problem too.

Answer (score 0):

For those who might be seeing this issue on their cicd pipelines but not on their locals. Check to see if you adjusted the casing for your file/directory names. Git didn't pick up the file renames for me.

This answer helped me fix my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23609455/22479271

Answer (score 0):

I was having a different reason. Documenting it for others below.

I started to get this error, the moment I added `metro.config.js` to my app. I copied the contents from a tutorial as below:

```
/**
 * Metro configuration for React Native
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 */

const {getDefaultConfig} = require('metro-config');

module.exports = async () => {
  const {
    resolver: {assetExts, sourceExts},
  } = await getDefaultConfig();
  return {
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== 'svg'),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'svg'],
    },
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer'),
      getTransformOptions: async () => ({
        transform: {
          experimentalImportSupport: false,
          inlineRequires: true,
        },
      }),
    },
  };
};
```

But, I had to do the following changes to make it work:

- change the require path to `expo/metro-config` from just `metro-config`
- change the `getDefaultConfig()` call to `getDefaultConfig(__dirname)`
- extend existing configs, instead of overriding them

Here is the updated `metro.config.js` that worked for me:

```
/**
 * Metro configuration for React Native
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 */

const {getDefaultConfig} = require('expo/metro-config');

module.exports = async () => {
  const defaultConfig = await getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
  const {
    resolver: {assetExts, sourceExts},
  } = defaultConfig;
  
  return {
    ...defaultConfig,
    resolver: {
      ...defaultConfig.resolver,
      assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== 'svg'),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'svg'],
    },
    transformer: {
      ...defaultConfig.transformer,
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer'),
      getTransformOptions: async () => ({
        transform: {
          experimentalImportSupport: false,
          inlineRequires: true,
        },
      }),
    },
  };
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Using this worked for me npm cache add package name@version
example: npm cache add react-native-paper@0.9.1

Answer (score -2):

I had the exact same problem — fix was `babel-preset-react-native-stage-0`, instead of `babel-preset-react-native`.

Comment: Where should that line be?