# React Native App - The development server returned response error code: 500

Tags: android, react-native, genymotion

I'm asking again because my case wasn't solved on previous answers.
I created a React Native App that works perfectly on Snack, but then I wanted to try it on Expo(I want to add some modules that Snack can't load).
So, I used `create-react-native-app` to make my project.
Then, after editing the code, I tried to launch it using the Genymotion emulator, but everytime I do it, the below error occurs :
[image]

I can't understand what's wrong with it?
I already tried removing node_modules folder, changing React Native and Babel version and reinstalling the project with `npm install`.
Also, in console, it shows me this error:

```
22:33:56: Unable to resolve ./components/AssetExample" from "./C:\\Users\\danie\\HC\\App.js`: The module `./components/AssetExample` could not be found"
22:33:56: Failed building JavaScript bundle
```

but I don't know where should this module be imported? package.json or package-lock.json?

I launch it in Genymotion using the following:

```
cd HC
npm start android
```

What can I do? Please help me.

React Native version: 0.55.2

Babel(preset React Native) version: ^4.0.0

**Edit:** Project Structure & code as requested, I created the repository on GitHub: https://github.com/DanielVip3/HC
^ I didn't push the node_modules folder because it was too large, but I think you already know: it contains all the modules that React Native uses.

Comment: You’ll likely get more response if you add the smallest version of your code that shows this behaviour to the question; without it there isn’t much to work with.

Answer (score 0):

The application is looking for ./components/AssetExample in your own application folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please give us your project structure and the code in App.js file (also make sure you export AssetExample class in AssetExample.js file.
What i understand you are trying to do is (probably) that in App.js you import AssetExample from "./components/AssetExample", so possible errors are:
1) path is wrong
2) you don't export default AssetExample in AssetExample.js
```

Comment: just edited my code to add the project structure and the code. Anyway, I already thought that, but no, I'm not importing manually ./components/AssetExample, I think that a module that I have tries to import it.

Comment: Hmm, maybe then try:
    npm start --reset-cache , if i relate it to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985027/unable-to-resolve-module-in-react-native-app)