# Unable to resolve modules in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, npm-install

Don't know what happened, was just trying to install new dependencies and all of sudden these error start appearing.

[image]

I tried installing `npm install react-navtive-paper` but all in vain.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `node_modules` folder and reinstalling the dependencies?

Comment: You may find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985027/unable-to-resolve-module-in-react-native-app

Comment: @MCNaveen Deleting folder and installing again worked! Thanks