# Fixing Git folder case problems in macOS

Tags: git

I have a codebase that has a folder that was written with an upper case letter. I changed it to lower case and committed it.

Before: `Onboarding`

After: `onboarding`

Now I saw that all my changes are duplicated when I commit changes to files in that folder.

```
screens/onboarding/Registration.js
screens/Onboarding/Registration.js
```

Strange thing is, there is no upper case folder in my filesystem anymore, but somehow Git sees them and even finds changes in them.

How do I get rid of these duplicated files in the (non-existent?) upper case folder?

Comment: What is the value for your `core.ignoreCase` config value? Haven't worked out exactly how this would play out, but I'm wondering if it's set to true and malfunctioning because your filesystem is in fact case-sensitive...

Comment: `core.ignoreCase` is set to `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your present situation, you should be able to do a

```
git rm -r -- screens/Onboarding
# add --cached if the folder is not on your disk
git commit -m "Record deletion of screens/Onboarding"
```

But in your original case, you might have done instead:

```
git mv -f screens/Onboarding screens/onboarding
```

(using `git mv --force`, [since Git 2.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24979063/6309))