# Filename capitalization changes ignored in git Git on Windows

Tags: git, windows-10, visual-studio-code, filenames

I have a reactjs application and I am normalizing all file names to be lowercase to comply with [Nodejs best practices](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#stick-with-lowercase)

However when I change file names within Visual Studio Code, these changes are ignored by git, so I am unable to commit my changes.

I followed the steps outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523849/changing-capitalization-of-filenames-in-git) to turn off git's default file case ignoring for Windows, but nothing changes after I verify it is toggled to off -- my file name changes occur but git doesn't pick up changes to allow me to commit them. switching branches resets the filename capitalization changes I have made.

How can I commit my changes to file name capitalization in git?

Answer (score 8):

The problem arises with file systems that are case insensitive. So myfile.js and myFile.js are actually the same file as far as the file system is concerned.

So to get around it you need to use a different filename, commit it, and then rename again, like this

```
git mv myFile.js temp-myfile.js
git commit -am "Temp file rename"
```

followed by

```
git mv temp-myfile.js myfile.js
git commit -am "Renamed to final destination
```

That should do the trick

Answer (score 5):

If you do `git mv FileName fileNameTemp` and then `git mv fileNameTemp fileName` will solve your problem without the need to commit.

Comment: I get an error: "not under version control, source=src/app.js, destination=src/AppTemp.js

Comment: try ```mv FileName fileNameTemp && mv fileNameTemp fileName && git add fileName```

Comment: `mv FileName fileNameTemp && mv fileNameTemp fileName && git add fileName` doesn't work