# Git on Windows: "merging" 2 directories with the same name but different case

Tags: windows, git, directory, case-sensitive

The word "merge" does not refer to a git merge, but just moving all the files to the same directory.

We somehow came to have two directories with the same name but different cases in our git repository. Windows is case-insensetive in this respect so it works fine just checking out all the files from both directories into one directory on disk.

Still would like to get rid of this "duality"

Is there a way to fix this using Windows git clients?

I've tried git mv, but it appears to be case insensetive. I expected it to move only the files that are under the lowercase version of the directory but it moved both directories.

Comment: I don't use Windows so I can't test this and won't close as a duplicate (yet?), but see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10523849/1256452

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
git mv myfolder tmp_folder
git mv tmp_folder MyFolder
```

Even though it initially removed  `MyFolder` and moved all the files under `tmp_folder` after issuing the second `mv` it worked as expected staging renames for the files in `myfolder` to be moved to `MyFolder`