# File not modified after successful pushed commit containing change

Tags: git, github

The 7 minutes old master commit below contains changes to a file called "SearchTerms.cs":

[image]

But as you can see in that file's history, its latest modification is some older commit, and indeed if I open the file, I don't find any of the modifications from the commit above.

[image]

This history is from the master branch. How is this possible, and can it be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are looking at the history of another file: one in the `Akeneo` folder, instead of the `akeneo` folder.

Ideally, [rename one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49817659/6309) in order to keep only one folder, instead of two with different case.

Comment: It's like the smaller the issue, the harder it is to find. Spot on, it fixed it, thanks!

Comment: Would this be the same if the OP was on OSX?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes, it is best to keep only one folder with one case.

Comment: (I only say this because in my osx I cannot create two folders with same spelling, but different cases)

Comment: @evolutionxbox I agree, but it still is more error-prone (while technically possible)