# There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app, react-router-dom

I just initialized a new project using create-react-app and everything was ok until I installed react-router-dom. Every time I start my development server I get a warning

```
./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* C:\Users\hisza\Desktop\weatherapp\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--5-oneOf-3!C:\Users\hisza\Desktop\weatherApp\node_modules\webpack\buildin\global.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\hisza\Desktop\weatherapp\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--5-oneOf-3!C:\Users\hisza\Desktop\weatherApp\node_modules\mini-create-react-context\dist\esm\index.js
* C:\Users\hisza\Desktop\weatherapp\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--5-oneOf-3!C:\Users\hisza\Desktop\weatherapp\node_modules\webpack\buildin\global.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\hisza\Desktop\weatherapp\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--5-oneOf-3!C:\Users\hisza\Desktop\weatherapp\node_modules\@pmmmwh\react-refresh-webpack-plugin\client\utils\safeThis.js
```

I found out it can be problem with my imports, but there is no problem with my imports. Every time i remove line with my react-router-dom import everything is ok.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
```

I tried removing node_modules and installing npm again using different prompts (gitBash, cmd and powershell) but I still get this warning. Any ideas how to fix that? Currently my 'project' is just Root.js with some empty directories.

Comment: Can you, please, share your `package.json` file?

Comment: [package.json](https://pastiebin.com/6024f2580bd6c)

Comment: I think that the problem is this one:
"react-router": "^5.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
Try to remove "react-router" and keep "react-router-dom"

Comment: Still got the same warning

Comment: Some user had similar issues, maybe this comment can help https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25460#issuecomment-526273944 in that case was a TS proj but it may be related to VS Code too https://stackoverflow.com/a/56058098/8534482

Comment: Well, can you please specify which of the two links worked for you? So I can put the procedure as an answer that can be useful for other user with the same problem.

Comment: oh sorry, second link helped me, that one with cleaning cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is thrown after installing react-router-dom. Try removing it and see those errors gone. This particular error does not affect the codes you write. Even if you upload to heroku or netlify, it would be fine. I think it is a bug they are to fix soon.

Comment: I don't remember what I've done, but everything works, I think I just reinstalled react-router-dom