# create react app error compiling on windows where files have similar names with different casing

Tags: typescript, windows, visual-studio-code, create-react-app

I'm getting compile errors on many of my files. One issue seems to be that running my `package.json` script: "react-scripts start" causes errors where I have two files in the same location with similar names.

For example when I have two files in the same location:
`src\Context\GlobalContext\globalContext.ts`

`src\Context\GlobalContext\GlobalContext.tsx`

And I try to import the `GlobalContext.tsx` file, the compiler seems to be ignoring my `GlobalContext.tsx` file and looking in `globalContext.ts`.

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/App.tsx 14:0-66

Module not found: Error: Cannot find file: 'GlobalContext.ts' does not match the corresponding name on disk: '.\src\Context\GlobalContext\globalContext.ts'.

...

src\App.tsx
  Line 9:27:   Casing of ./Context/GlobalContext/GlobalContext does not match the underlying filesystem  import/no-unresolved
  Line 10:25:  Casing of ./Context/UserContext/UserContext does not match the underlying filesystem      import/no-unresolved
```

It seems to work both ways though. This error suggests that the compiler is looking at a `SearchContext.tsx` file when it should be looking at a `searchContext.ts` file. The compiler seems to be ignoring the 'x' in the `.tsx` and getting very confused:

```
TS1149: File name 'C:/../src/Context/SearchContext/searchContext.ts'
differs from already included file name
'C:/.../src/Context/SearchContext/SearchContext.ts'
only in casing.
```

This has never been a problem on Linux, and wasn't previously a problem on my Windows OS until today. I also appear to be having similar issues with my Node/Express server. I installed ts-node

I have tried:

1. Reloading my VS Code
2. Restarting my machine
3. Toggling my `tsconfig.ts` `compilerOptions`: `"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false`
4. Clearing my VS Code cache ([all above solutions from this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51197940/file-name-differs-from-already-included-file-name-only-in-casing-on-relative-p))
5. Restart the typescript server:  opening the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) --> Select `Typescript: Restart TS`
6. Removing my VS code workspace ([as per this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56058098/11664580))
7. Renaming files fixes the issue. For example, changing `GlobalContext.tsx` to `GlobalContextProvider.tsx` in both the import statement and the file name prevents the error.

Comment: Maybe this answer will solve your problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77896843/8497363

Answer (score 3):

It looks like my issue is discussed in this blog post: https://briandesousa.net/?p=870 and also in this github thread https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21736

I'd been working previously on Linux, which imports with case sensitivity, whereas Windows and MacOS don't. So where I have two files of the same name but with different cases, Windows can't tell the difference - even when the have different `.ts`/`.tsx` extensions.

It seems that the `tsconfig.ts` `compilerOptions:` `"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true` setting, simply provides warnings when there are inconsistent casings, it doesn't actually fix anything.

There doesn't seem to be a simple way to get Windows to distinguish by case sensitivity so the solution is to rename all of my similar files.