# How to fix "Module not found" error when deploying NextJS app to Netlify

Tags: next.js, netlify

I'm trying to deploy my NextJS App to Netlify but it keeps showing the error
`Module not found: Can't resolve '../components/home/home' in '/opt/build/repo/pages'`in the build log.
But locally the build command didn't result in any errors.

My build settings in Netlify are:
**Base directory**  *Not set*
**Build command**  *npm run build*
**Publish directory**  *.next*
**Builds** *Active*

Deploy log contains this error message

```
7:06:59 AM: ./pages/index.js
7:06:59 AM: Module not found: Can't resolve '../components/home/home' in '/opt/build/repo/pages'
7:06:59 AM: > Build failed because of webpack errors
7:06:59 AM: ​
7:06:59 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
7:06:59 AM:   "build.command" failed                                        
7:06:59 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
7:06:59 AM: ​
7:06:59 AM:   Error message
7:06:59 AM:   Command failed with exit code 1: npm run build (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
7:06:59 AM: ​
7:06:59 AM:   Error location
7:06:59 AM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
7:06:59 AM:   npm run build
7:06:59 AM: ​
7:06:59 AM:   Resolved config
7:06:59 AM:   build:
7:06:59 AM:     command: npm run build
7:06:59 AM:     commandOrigin: ui
7:06:59 AM:     environment:
7:06:59 AM:       - NEXT_PRIVATE_TARGET
7:06:59 AM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/.next
7:06:59 AM:     publishOrigin: ui
7:06:59 AM:   plugins:
7:06:59 AM:     - inputs: {}
7:06:59 AM:       origin: ui
7:06:59 AM:       package: '@netlify/plugin-nextjs'
7:06:59 AM: Caching artifacts
```

Answer (score 4):

I have found the solution to my own problem.
It's related to Windows case insensitive whereas Netlify uses Linux servers which are!
So, I had to rename all my lowercased named components to uppercase and it worked.

These articles have helped me.
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/16179
[Changing capitalization of filenames in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523849/changing-capitalization-of-filenames-in-git)

I hope it will help someone in the future.