# GitHub believes I have two Src folders when there is just one

Tags: visual-studio, github

In the GitHub web UI, my repo displays "Src" and "src" folders, and some files appear in one and most files in the other. Locally, there is a single "src" folder containing all files (Windows 11).

I have poked around the web interface and Visual Studio while also trying to find specific references in Google, but so far no luck.

I need to consolidate these into a single location, but since local storage does not match what is seen on the web, it's not clear how to achieve this goal.

Comment: Git generally doesn't do great in my experience with capitalization variants. You'll want to get it straightened out as soon as possible, and the fix merged into as many branches as you're likely to use again, as going back and forth across the fix line will give you grief.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523849/how-do-you-change-the-capitalization-of-filenames-in-git/ should start you down the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue while preserving history, which is a fear I had going in.

In a separate branch, I renamed the local src folder to xsrc and pushed. I then renamed the folder to src and again pushed. (The intermediate name of the folder should not be relevant, just that it differed.)

I initiated a pull request into the parent branch, and it simply reflected the net renaming of files and *not* any adds or deletes that were implied by the original renaming steps, and completing the merge preserved the original history of all files, all now displayed within a single "src" directory.

Comment: Are you perhaps on macOS, using a case-insensitive file system?

Comment: No, it's Windows.