# Git Change a Bulk of Files (Images) to Lowercase

Tags: git

I got 100 of images which I needed to rename from .JPG to .jpg. I already wrote a gulp task and renamed them all. Now Git is not recognizing the change.

I found this on single files:
[I change the capitalization of a directory and Git doesn't seem to pick up on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899582/i-change-the-capitalization-of-a-directory-and-git-doesnt-seem-to-pick-up-on-it)

But I don't want to do this on each image by hand is it possible to use s.th. like this

`git mv **/*/.JPG **/*.temp`

`git mv **/*/.temp **/*.jpg`

The images are all in diff. folders! E.g. `src/a, src/a/b src/b ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
for file in $(git ls-files '*.JPG'); 
do git mv -f $file $(echo $file |sed 's/\.JPG/\.jpg/'); done
```

- `git ls-files` lists all files => `'*.JPG'` filters
- `git mv -f` moves the files (-f = force, which is required)
- `$file` returns the original filename
- `$(echo $file |sed 's/\.JPG/\.jpg/')`is the new filename

Helpful threads:

[git rename many files and folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984722/git-rename-many-files-and-folders)

[How to rename large number of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981208/how-to-rename-large-number-of-files)

Comment: The shell will do simple string work, `mv -f "$file" "${file%.JPG}.jpg"` instead of your `echo`+`sed`.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
for line in $(find -type f -name '*.JPG'
               | sed 's@\(.*\)\.JPG@\1.JPG \1.jpg/')
do
    git mv $line
done
```

If you already renamed your files you just need to `git add` them.
Since they haven't changed `git` will notice they all have the the same blob
object and [setup the renaming](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository#Moving-Files).  If you don't have any other unknown or
changed files in your git working dir, one possible way is:

```bash
for path in $(git status --porcelain | sed 's/.. //')
do
    git add "$l"
done
```

Comment: I already renamed them. So I guess I have to use the second solution. Can you explain a bit more to the solution. I'm always afraid when doing crazy moves on my git repo.

Comment: You don't need to be afraid, as long as you have a clone somewhere with your previous repo status.

Comment: Regarding the operation, you're just telling git that some files should be marked for deletion and addition: git is smart enough to known they are indeed the same file and then mark them as a "file movement" (renaming).

Comment: Ok thanks I just copied that into my console. When I do the first solution (I took the unchanged images) it gives me `$line: not a valid identifier`

Answer (score 1):

There is a small change to the answer given by @jvdm to make the first code snippet work.

```
for line in $(find -type f -name '*.JPG'
              | sed 's@\(.*\)\.JPG@\1.JPG \1.jpg/')
do
    git mv $line
done
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work either:
`find: illegal option -- t
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]
-bash: command substitution: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token \`|'
-bash: command substitution: line 2: \`              | sed 's@\(.*\)\.JPG@\1.JPG \1.jpg/''
`